# Checking file existence in folder(s) and then checking it's filesize()

Tags: php

I am storing attachment images in my database with its full path: i.e. in the attachment column, data like this will be portrayed:

```
user_data/attached_files/conor-mcgregor.jpg
```

The image is stored in user_data > attached_files > images are here.

What I am trying to do is get the image name from the database, checking if the image name exists in the `attached_files` folder and then check its size.

I of course have to obtain the `basename` of the image, which I have done:

```
$get_msg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_messages);
$img_url = $get_msg['attachment'];

$file = $img_url;
$arrPathInfo = pathinfo($file);
$shortened_url = $arrPathInfo['basename'];
```

If I echo `$shortened_url` I get `conor-mcgregor.jpg`, which is valid, an image of that name exists in the `attached_files` folder. But when I run this test, to see if the file exists, it returns false:

```
if (file_exists($shortened_url)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

So, If the file exists with the `conor-mcgregor.jpg`, then (for now) return true, but eventually I would do `filesize($shortened_url);`. And if it doesn't exist, return false.

The file does exist, but I don't understand why it is printing false?

Comment: Is your php script located in the root directory of your website or /user_data/attached_files/ ?

Comment: `user_data/attached_files/` would need the full system path for it, as in `/var/user/public/user_data/attached_files/` or a relative path. `../user_data/attached_files/` type of thing. Error reporting would help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `is_file()` instead of `file_exists()` for your case

[PHP is_file manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)

I consider your php script is located in root folder of your website, then check file existence in sub folder should look like:

```
$fpath = "user_data/attached_files/{$shortened_url}";

if (file_exists($fpath)) {
    echo "true";
    // echo filesize($fpath);
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see my fault. The file I am working on is not in the root directory, which was why it could not find the file. Just out of curiosity, why do you have `{}` in this line: `{$shortened_url}`? I have never seen that before.

Comment: It's not necessary for simple php variable names inside "strings" but will prevent php from putting backslash for variables containing ' like "{$var['key']}". Also helps to recognize php variables inside strings just visually

Comment: You can find more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 0):

```
// you need to include the path from the file the php is executed
$shortened_url = 'user_data/attached_files/'.$arrPathInfo['basename'];

if (file_exists($shortened_url)) {
    echo filesize($shortened_url).' bytes';
} else {
 echo 'no file';
}
```